# Change HTML style for given data model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mvvm

I've got some data that I'm playing with via some AJAX "GET" requests.  Right now, I'm just putting the data inside of table rows.  This is list view of my data.  However, if I also wanted to offer a thumbnail view of my data or a dekstop-like view of my data, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

I've read a little bit on Javascript frameworks like Backbone, Angular, Ember, and Knockout, but is this even the right approach?  If it helps to understand my issue my data is a bunch of files and their metadata.  I'd love to have those three views of them, but I don't want to have my Javascript just be a ton of searching through DOM nodes, I'd rather have some data consistency and have the DOM render data according to what view I choose.

Comment: Rather than close the question.  Should I move it to another StackExchange site?

Comment: Using one of the mentioned frameworks will certainly be a good approach. This way you'll have one set of data and multiple views with different templates bound to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Klaster_1, I use Backbone myself, it is definitely not doing a ton of searching through DOM nodes. It is a neat approach with one set of data and multiple views and templates.

An alternative would be using CSS and JQuery to dynamically add or remove classes depending on the view you choose. But that is the approach which would be the equivalent of a ton of searching through DOM nodes.